# Crinsane Cart is not being updated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am giving him numerical quantity but it is not being updated in Cart. Where am I making a mistake?

**cart.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->id,$cartItem->qty], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

                      <input class="qty"  min="0" max="" name="qty" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}" title="qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="text">
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-price" data-title="Price">{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                    {{--<td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Total">$2.26</td>--}}
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <td class="product-remove">

                        <input style="position: relative; top: 21px;" class="button success small" type="image" src="images/refresh.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/refresh2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/refresh.png'" alt="Submit" width="30" height="30">
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Please display all data of **$cartItem** variable in your blade file

Comment: This was only update code. I am successfully displaying all items inside the cart and also being able to delete them.

Comment: Please display your **cart.update** route code

Comment: Route::resource('/cart', 'CartController');

Comment: Route::get('/cart/add-item/{id}', 'CartController@addItem')->name('cart.addItem');

Comment: can you post the update controller class?

Comment: public function update($id,$qty)
    {
        Cart::update($id,['qty'=>$qty]);
        return back();
    }

Comment: may be **cart.update** route come from **Route::resource('/cart', 'CartController');** am i right?

Comment: Yep  Exactly. For sure

Comment: Please write **php artisan route:list** in your terminal/cmd and give me output.

Comment: https://imgur.com/kWvyBKC

Comment: Please check your **cart.update** route and pass only **one** parameter like **cart/{cart}** and you pass **two** parameters in form (i.g {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->id,$cartItem->qty], 'method' => 'POST']) !!})

Comment: I have used  {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->id], 'method' => 'POST'])  !!}
But no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your cart.update route and pass only **one** parameter like `cart/{cart}` and you pass **two** parameters in form (i.e `{!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->id,$cartItem->qty], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`)

Comment: I have used {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!} But no

Comment: When I used cart/{cart} it gave error. But after undo and passing one parameter no error but it didn't work too.

Comment: @Faiez : please show code of update function in CartController

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Cart::update($id,['qty'=>$request->qty]);
        return back();
    }

Comment: Can you please create new route for update function like:
Route::post('/cart/update/{id}', 'CartController@update')->name('cartupdate');

**And** your form like:
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['cartupdate',$cartItem->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

Comment: Route::get('cart/{cart}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');

Comment: your method is get and you mention post in your form and update have always post method